# sbt-assembly not working for scala 2.12.1

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-assembly, scala-2.12

My project build, when using scalaVersion to be 2.11.8. When I switch to scalaVersion 2.12.1, I get the error that the symbol `assembly` in `mainClass in assembly := ...` cannot be found. Is https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly not working with scala 2.12.1 yet?

So

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.8",
```

works, but

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.1",
```

does not work.

Comment: Your version of Scala should have no effect on your sbt plugins, since they're all run in the sbt process with Scala 2.10. Can you include the exact changes you made to your `build.sbt` file?

Comment: @jkinkead: It is really just the version I change (see question).

Comment: Can you include a minimal reproduction case, and the version of assembly you have set in your plugins file?

Comment: @jkinkead: A MWE takes a bit of time. For now: I added the line `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")` to the file `project/assembly.sbt`

Comment: I can't reproduce trivially. Given that the scala version shouldn't affect your build at all, my only guess is that you have some sort of edit error in your `build.sbt` file (or you were missing declaring the plugin entirely before your last comment).

Answer (score 1):

use below sbt assembly version
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")

it worked for scala 2.10

Comment: Question about scala 2.12.1, not scala 2.10